# What's the best practice to use created resources in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

I will start a new Terraform project on AWS. The VPC is already created and i want to know what's the best way to integrate it in my code. Do i have to create it again and Terraform will detect it and will not override it ? Or do i have to use Data source for that ? Or is there other best way like Terraform Import ?

I want also to be able in the future to deploy the entire infrastructure in other Region or other Account.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use in Terraform resources already in AWS (created manually)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336333/how-to-use-in-terraform-resources-already-in-aws-created-manually)

Answer (score 11):

When it comes to integrating with existing objects, you first have to decide between two options: you can either import these objects into Terraform and use Terraform to manage them moving forward, or you can leave them managed by whatever existing system and use them in Terraform by reference.

---

If you wish to use Terraform to manage these existing objects, you must first write a configuration for the object as if Terraform were going to create it itself:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  # fill in here all the same settings that the existing object already has

  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

# Can then use that vpc's id in other resources using:
#    aws_vpc.example.id
```

But then rather than running `terraform apply` immediately, you can first run `terraform import` to instruct Terraform to associate this resource block with the existing VPC using its id assigned by AWS:

```
terraform import aws_vpc.example vpc-abcd1234
```

If you then run `terraform plan` you should see that no changes are required, because Terraform detected that the configuration matches the existing object. If Terraform *does* propose some changes, you can either accept them by running `terraform apply` or continue to update the configuration until it matches the existing object.

Once you have done this, Terraform will consider itself the owner of the VPC and will thus plan to update it or destroy it on future runs if the configuration suggests it should do so. If any other system was previously managing this VPC, it's important to stop it doing so or else this other system is likely to conflict with Terraform.

---

If you'd prefer to keep whatever existing system is managing the VPC, you can also use the [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) feature to look up the existing VPC without putting Terraform in charge of it.

In this case, you might use [the `aws_vpc` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html), which can look up VPCs by various attributes. A common choice is to look up a VPC by its tags, assuming your environment has a predictable tagging scheme that allows you to describe the single VPC you are looking for:

```
data "aws_vpc" "example" {
  tags = {
    Name = "example-VPC-name"
  }
}

# Can then use that vpc's id in other resources using:
#    data.aws_vpc.example.id
```

In some cases users will introduce additional indirection to find the VPC some other way than by querying the AWS VPC APIs directly. That is a more advanced configuration and the options here are quite broad, but for example if you are using SSM Parameter Store you could place the VPC into a parameter store parameter and retrieve it using [the `aws_ssm_parameter` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html).

If the existing system managing the VPC is CloudFormation, you could also use [`aws_cloudformation_export`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/cloudformation_export.html) or [`aws_cloudformation_stack`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/cloudformation_stack.html) to retrieve the information from the CloudFormation API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to manage it via terraform moving forward then you can import existing resources into your terraform state. Here is the usage page for it https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html

You will have to define a resource block inside of your configuration for the vpc first. You could do something like:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "existing" {
  cidr_block       = "172.16.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "prod"
  }
}
```

and then on the cli run the command

```
terraform import aws_vpc.existing <vpc-id>
```

Make sure you run a terraform plan afterwards, because terraform may try to make changes to it. You kind of have to reverse engineer it a bit, by adding all the necessary configuration to the aws_vpc resource. Once it is aligned, terraform will not attempt to change it. You can then re-use this to deploy to other accounts and regions.

As you suggested, you could use a data source for the vpc. This can be useful if you want to manage it outside of terraform, instead of having the potential to destroy the vpc if it is run by an inexperienced user.

Some customers I've worked with prefer to manage resources like vpcs/subnets (and other core infrastructure) in separate terraform scripts that only senior engineers have access to. This can avoid the disaster scenarios where people destroy the underlying infrastructure by accident.

I personally prefer managing all my terraform code in a git repository that is then deployed using a CI/CD tool, even if it's just myself working on it. Some people may not see the value in spending the time creating the pipeline though and may stick with running it locally.

This post has some great recommendations on running terraform in an an automated environment https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/development/running-terraform-in-automation